# Get user's information from Oracle APEX public page?

Tags: oracle, authentication, oracle-apex

Just need to verify if it is impossible to get the username of client's environment on a public APEX page?
That is, to find something that can identify the user, without asking the user to identify themselves.

Obviously the following doesn't work, as all the SQL statements are run on the server:

```
select sys_context( 'userenv', 'os_user' ) from dual;
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'll answer this once I figure out who you are without you telling me ;)

Comment: Seriously, you can get some information from the "CGI client variables" set in the HTTP header. Use OWA_UTIL.GET_CGI_ENV(<variable_name>). There really is no such thing as "the username of client's environment" in there, except if your site has single signon: see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/establishing-user-identity-through-authentication.html#GUID-05061E24-672C-4E8E-870B-A4E8D0251523

Comment: Thanks, Stew. Do you have an example? I was actually looking for user's domain username (or something similar), so that I could use it for APEX_LDAP.search to find the value of a given attribute of that specific user.

Comment: Is the domain username in the HTTP header? If so try OWA_UTIL.GET_CGI_ENV('REMOTE_USER'). Otherwise it's no use.

Comment: Thanks again. No, it is not there. No value returns for the REMOTE_USER variable.
I guess I need to find out how to set the domain username in the header, if there are really no other ways to solve this.